# Request word segmentation from solr analysis service

Tags: solr, lucene, cjk

I've installed solr with its Chinese word segmentation package. It works fine in http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/analysis.jsp. The solr analysis tool is working fine with Chinese word segmentation package.

My question is, how can I pass a word segmentation request to solr, and how can I get a good response?  I've tried to access "http://localhost:8983/solr/analysis/field?analysis.fieldtype=text&q=adfasd" from the browser, but it fails.

Please offer me some hints, keyword, API.

Comment: OP: I wanted to add the relevant [tag:text-segmentation] tag to your question, but your use of a localhost URL prevents me from doing so without also editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost:8983/solr/analysis/field?analysis.fieldtype=text&analysis.fieldvalue=keyword&wt=json`
will be return json file. keyword will be the sentence which u want to be split into keyword

reference here:

```
http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/handler/FieldAnalysisRequestHandler.html
```